# Installing mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi to use django with apache2. I am using Ubuntu Linux system. After installing apache and mysql i tried to install libapache2-mod-wsgi as suggested in many tutorials online. Installation went good so next step enable mod-wsgi. I get the following error when I try to enable it

```
sudo a2enmod mod-wsgi
ERROR: Module mod-wsgi does not exist!
```

but this:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
Reading package List... Done
Creating depencies tree
Reading current state description
libapache2-mod-wsgi is allready final version.
0 updated, 0  installed, 0  remmoved και 0 upgraded.
```

which probalby means it is allready installed. How can I install it

PS: Am I at the right forum for this question?

Answer (score 2):

It's called `mod_wsgi`, not `mod-wsgi`.

Comment: To be honest it is plain wsgi now. Had to do a2enmod wsgi. Thank u for answering though :)

Answer (score 1):

use pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install mod_wsgi
```

Comment: Installing with ``pip`` is a bit different to using operating system packages for mod_wsgi. When using operating system packages is up to you to then configure the system Apache installation. If using ``pip``, it installs ``mod_wsgi-express``, which allows you to run up Apache/mod_wsgi on non privileged port without you needing to configure anything. So really two different ways of working with mod_wsgi. You can also use ``pip`` method to sort of get the first outcome by afterwards running ``sudo mod_wsgi-express install-module``, but then need to configure main Apache installation again.